# How to parse cid value from HTML Tags BODY or Div?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to parse cid value from html in the email content to download them and replace later:

```html
<body style=
"background-image: url(cid:1A41BAD0-28D1-4EAA-AD4A-4E867FEC28E4/bg_pattern.jpg); margin: 0px; padding: 0px; word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space; background-position: 50% 0px; background-repeat: initial initial;"
class="">
<div style=
"background-image: url(cid:1A41BAD0-28D1-4EAA-AD4A-4E867FEC28E4/bg_pattern.jpg); background-position: 50% 0px; background-repeat: initial initial;"
class="">
```

In the original javascript code they parsed the img tag but I don't know how to modify that to parse another tag.
https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/wiki/Embedding-images-in-HTML-rendered-message

Could you please show me the tricks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var style = div.getAttribute("style");
var cid = style.substring(style.indexOf("cid:")+4, style.indexOf(")"));
alert(cid);
```

```html
<body style=
"background-image: url(cid:1A41BAD0-28D1-4EAA-AD4A-4E867FEC28E4/bg_pattern.jpg); margin: 0px; padding: 0px; word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space; background-position: 50% 0px; background-repeat: initial initial;"
class="">
<div style=
"background-image: url(cid:1A41BAD0-28D1-4EAA-AD4A-4E867FEC28E4/bg_pattern.jpg); background-position: 50% 0px; background-repeat: initial initial;"
class="">
```

use getAttribute and do some string parsing..

Comment: Can you release a function that can return the tag that have attribute "background-image" ?

something like :
function imageElements() {
    var imageNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    return [].slice.call(imageNodes);
}

Thanks,

Comment: Im not sure I unerstand your comment, but you can use this to select elements by attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll the other answer provides a demonstration of this.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("*[style]");
x.forEach(function(tag, index) {
    var style = tag.getAttribute("style");
    var array = style.split('background-image: url(cid:')
    if(array.length && array[1]) { 
    // here you will get cid
       var cid = array[1].split(');')[0]
    }
})
```

Comment: i would split on just "cid:" because you dnt know if that space will be there or not. could miss some.

Comment: I would say we should follow same and there should be some consistency. what if there is a tag with style attribute but no background-image and still have something that may have string cid: in it

Comment: Good point, however "cid" is not valid css. I would think he'd want to replace any instances of it.